# Forward from port 80 to my proxy server wont work

Tags: linux, iptables, proxy, squid, port-forwarding

I have a raspberry configured as a little server for doing some networking training, this is my current system version 
**Linux raspberrypi 4.14.98-v7+ #1200 SMP Tue Feb 12 20:27:48 GMT 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux**. Currently, my raspberry has a usb wirelss adapter for connecting to the internet (wlan0) and the lan port is plugged to another PC which goes out to the internet from the wireless interface.

Now i want to set up a proxy, i have already installed squid and run it with some simple configurations. Below my current **squid.conf** without comments:

```
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl mynetwork src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow mynetwork
http_access deny all
http_port 3128
http_port 3129 intercept
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 500 16 256
refresh_pattern -i \.(gif|png|jpeg|ico)$ 3600   90%     43200
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
```

Firstly, i want to make it as transparent proxy without configuring every browser settings, but after reading a lot of tutorial which explains how to redirect from a port to anothe, no one of them did not work because the proxy does not log the activity of the PC in the **access.log** file.

My **nat** **tables**:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt  source      destination
REDIRECT   tcp  --   anywhere    anywhere      tcp dpt:http redir ports 3129

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source       destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source       destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source       destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere    anywhere
```

My **filter** **table**:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

In conclusion, i missed some configurations? Or this iptable rules are wrong for my purpose?

Comment: A transparent proxy is one which systems in your network can (and will) use WITHOUT explicitly confirming a proxy server in the OS or web browser. One half of the equation is configuring the proxy server itself to work in a transparent mode, the other half is configuring your network, in SOHO networks typically on the gateway router, to intercept web traffic from your systems and to force it through the proxy server. Your question seems to indicate that you've only tried to solve half the equation haven't done any such network configuration to make the second part of the equation work.

Comment: @HBruijn I said "without configuring every browser settings", anyway can you be more clear about "network configuration" part?

Comment: You need a way to ensure that when your webbrowser send a web request to serverfault.com port 80 it does not go to the ServerFault webserver but instead to the system where your transparent proxy lives.  https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Intercept lists network configuration examples  for  a number of different device types

Comment: @HBruijn i followed the guide which you provide, in particular "Traffic Interception by Policy Routing" using Iptables. But when i run **tail** for having the access.log file and at the same time i open a new tab on my browser, the proxy doesn't log the activity, because in the access.log doesn't appear any new entry

Comment: Here is another policy based routing tutorial to route traffic from your gateway (rpi) to additional proxy box installed within your network - https://docs.diladele.com/tutorials/policy_based_routing_squid/index.html. From your description though it seems you need to run the squid on rpi? If so you'd need to setup local redirect iptables rules as explained in https://docs.diladele.com/tutorials/transparent_proxy_ubuntu/index.html

Comment: @Rafael Yes, i want to run squid on my raspberry. But in my view there is some forward issue because with tcpdump i can't catch any packet incoming from the client in particular form the squid's port, although i set port forwarding on my iptables